# How to add CREATE DATABASE and CREATE SCHEMA inside a PROCEDURE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to make this work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createDbandSchema AS
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE MYDB
    USE MYDB
    CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA
END
```

I got error

> a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or
>   trigger.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: I have the db name pass in as parameter in a procedure that ships to my client so that on deployment, my client can execute the procedure with the db name he/she chooses to setup everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create schema` statement must be the first in the batch, so it requires a nested scope.  The outer scope changes to the new database.  The inner scope runs `create schema` as the first statement of the batch:

```
create procedure createDbandSchema(@db sysname, @schema sysname)
as begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + quotename(@db);
    exec (@sql)
    set @sql = N'USE ' + quotename(@db) + '; exec (N''CREATE SCHEMA ' +
        quotename(@schema) + N''')';
    exec (@sql)
end
```

Comment: Yay that works. I also found this to work as well EXEC ('EXEC MYDB.dbo.sp_executesql N''CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA''')

Comment: Wow, `mydb.dbo.sp_executesql`. Yeah looks like that runs the procedure in the context of `mydb`. Nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use the CREATE SCHEMA syntax or, in SSMS, drill down through Databases -> YourDatabaseName -> Security -> Schemas. Right-click on the Schemas folder and select "New Schema..."

[image]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207005.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63f5c2/schema-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: The db is created dynamically